# I have a list of file names and line numbers. How can I modify these lines in place?

Tags: shell, text-processing

I have a list of file names and line numbers in the following format:

```
./foo.txt:1:(more characters)
./foo.txt:3:(more characters)
./bar.txt:10:(more characters)
```

The list could be from a file or it could be output by a process (for example, `grep -n`).

I want to append some fixed text to each of the referenced lines, modifying the files in place.

For example, if the file foo.txt contains the following text:

```
One
Two
Three
Four
```

I want it to be modified to contain:

```
One TODO
Two
Three TODO
Four
```

Similarly, " TODO" should be appended to line 10 of bar.txt.

How can I do this?

Comment: Passing file names like this is tricky. If the file name contains `:` or new line, it will fail.

Comment: Well when text is coming from a stream than you could use `sed` as follows: `... | sed 's/\(.*\)/\1 foo/'`  or `... | sed 's/.*/& foo/'`

Comment: @ValentinBajrami it seems to me that the intention is to edit the referenced files, not the stream/input itself.

Comment: @ValentinBajrami: JeffSchaller is correct. I updated the question to make this clearer, it now specifically states that "the referenced lines" are to be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your file names do contain neither `:` nor newline:

```bsh
echo "$list_of_file_names" | while IFS=: read -r file line text; do
  sed -i "$line"'s/$/ TODO/' "$file"
done
```

---

> **Note**: I think this is a pretty bad idea as
>
> - it is inefficient (runs `sed` for each line).
> - it will break on file names including `:` or `\n`.
>
> Better use `sed` or `awk` for finding matching files+lines **and** appending text to them.

Comment: Good caveat about the `:` or newline in the file name.

Comment: Using sed or awk for finding *and* updating also seems like a good idea, provided it is feasible - which may not be the case, depending on how the list is generated. In fact, in the application that motivated the question, the list comes from an (improvised) code analysis script that *is* built around a `grep` invocation, but performs some additional processing.

Answer (score 3):

One option: use ed!

```sh
while IFS=: read -r filename linenumber junk
do
  ed -s "$filename" <<< "$linenumber"$'s/$/ TODO/\nw\nq'
done < input
```

Comment: Does this have an advantage over using `sed` as per [@RoVo's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/514023/348551)? Seems like the solutions are pretty similar, but the `sed` invocation looks a bit more tidy to me.

Comment: I wanted to put together a `sed` solution that batched all the edits for a single file together, to save some I/O. For example: `sed -i -e 1s/$/TODO -e 3s/$/TODO ./foo.txt` ... but didn't. Implementation left as an exercise for another Answerer :)